# How the localhost port number of .NET Development Server set?

Tags: .net, localhost, port

I see that time to time localhost port number changes (http://localhost:1519/ ....).

Basically how does it being set or chosen? And when does it change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a random number:

> When you use the ASP.NET Development
>   Server to run a file-system Web site,
>   by default, the Web server is **invoked**
>   **on a randomly selected port** for
>   localhost.

Although you can specify it yourself by disabling dynamic ports.

Take a look at : [How to: Specify a Port for the ASP.NET Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This is no longer an option in VS 2013, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 5):

You can set it here:
Choose "Use dynamic port = false"
[alt text http://img110.imageshack.us/img110/8444/59650554.jpg](http://img110.imageshack.us/img110/8444/59650554.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

The setting is placed in the properties of the project. Right click your project file and chose the Web Tab. If it is set to Auto-assigned Port, the Visual studio would randomly give you a port number. But you could chose the Specific port to assign your own port number.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the properties window on the website, there is an option to assign it as dynamic or choose a fixed port called "Use dynamic port", set this to false and then choose your port number.