# MVC windows authentication grayed (greyed) out in project properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, windows-authentication, anonymous

I am trying to use Windows Authentication in a VS 2013, MVC 4 project that was originally done in VS2011.

It worked fine on VS2011, but when I moved to VS2013 on the same machine, using IIS 7 problems ensued.

I have windows authentication set in web.config (and anonymous authentication disabled):

```
<security>
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
  </authentication>
</security>
```

However, these attributes are grayed (greyed) out in the **"f4"** properties window for the VS2013 solution.

When I debug the program, I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error with Error Code 0x80070021

I have tried editing C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config applicationHost.config per similar posts in forums, and restarting the services, but the problem still persists.

Does anyone know how to please solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me is the following line in web.config -->

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Yes  have this also but the problem still persists

Comment: Does anyone have other ideas, please?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Development Server" properties being grayed out in the Project Properties? The web.config is separate from the "f4" properties specified there

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but it may help you --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/22824591/2395030

If you create a new project, are you able to edit these settings?

Comment: Thanks, still not what I need, however.

Comment: Hmm, are you able to toggle these settings in other projects? Just trying to get an idea if this is a systematic issue, or something specific to this VS project.. here's another link with some interesting information --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762538/iis-express-windows-authentication?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I can save them in other projects.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that upgrading an MVC project from VS 2011 to 2013 (at least if this happens) is not an easy thing to do.  I finally punted and started a new VS 2013 project and imported various controllers, views, etc. into that project, which actually worked surprisingly well.  If you reach this page in a search and some of the other sites with answers have been failing for you, you may wish to do likewise.