# While updating service reference i get error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a restful wcf service there are **GET** methods already exist. But when in interface I created **post method** like

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
UriTemplate = "createDemo")]
int createDemo(ObjectInfo obj);
```

I consumed this service in another asp.net website project, while updating service over there i get the "**HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component**" error. Now if I comment this post method from service interface. Service reference gets updated. I googled for the same but i didn't understand what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Start—>Run—> regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll

Start—>Run—> regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\msxml3.dll
```

Or

Delete the project Cache from the below location:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache

C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache
```

This is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Please go through this link for more details..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2013/03/08/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component.aspx

Hope it will help you.

> **Also Could you try the following:**
>   Clean the project and rebuild it.
>     Close the project go to its folder location and delete the bin and obj
>   folders.
>    Make sure that the references assemblies in the project are
>   located in the same location. To do so expand the References in the
>   project and check each assemblies Path in the properties window.

For Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, I suggest that you could try to delete the project cache which path likes:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache

C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache
```

Then run "devenv.exe /setup" to re-build the cache.

```
Start—>Run—> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe  /setup
```

Comment: @Shibhu Thanks for your solution but it didn't work.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2013. I deleted the content in ProjectTemplatesCache folder. But still same issue. Also tried last suggestion.

Comment: Hi Thanks, it worked when i deleted cache from C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache folder. Now while updating i get "port 2066 in use". Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: Updated the answer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.Please try it.

Comment: For "port 2066 in use" error please tried to change port number.Help Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013