# Visual studio 2013: Manually specify localhost port no. for website project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am working on an angular project in visual studio.

I have created a `Blank solution` visual studio then added the existing website.

```
Open VS>>New Project>>Blank Solution>>Right click solution>>Add existing web site>>select Folder>>F5
```

Due to some reason I have to run the website on the `localhost:8080` but the visual studio is setting the port itself.

How to change the running port to **8080**

I have googled a lot but the only solutions I found is for `ASP.net`.
like
[stackover flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013),
[microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx)

```
Alt+Enter is opening this property window
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of project is it? And how is the website hosted? IIS Express?

Comment: @poke I had created a `blank solution` then by using `add existing project` i had added my website then using `F5` I am running the project

Comment: I guess the project is not a Web Application.

Comment: What kind of a project is it?? It doesn't look like a web project.

Comment: @VikasBansal That does not really answer my questions. What is that project’s project type? Also check “start options” in the window from the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't change the project URL from within Visual Studio for Website projects.**

There are two working methods for me, Posting this answer after testing.

**First Option**

**Web Site Projects** don't have a .*proj file to store settings instead, the settings are set in the *solution* file.  In VS2013, the settings look something like this:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "TestWebSite", "http://localhost:56422", "{401397AC-86F6-4661-A71B-67B4F8A3A92F}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        ...
        SlnRelativePath = "..\..\WebSites\WebSite1\"
        DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual Basic"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Because the project is identified by the URL (including port), there isn't a way in the Visual studio UI to change this.  You should be able to modify the solution file though, and it should work.

Note: In your case to set the port to 8080 you must open visual studio in **Run as Administrator** mode. You MUST run Visual Studio as an administrator in order to open websites with a port less than 1000

Credit of this option goes to [Jimmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25071/jimmy) and [original answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22824591/2592042)

---

**Second Option**

To specify a port for any web site project that uses IIS Express:

1. First Add the existing website and run it once. So that it gets assigned in the IIS sites list.
2. In project go to Solution Explorer, right-click the project name and then click **Remove** or **Delete**; don't worry, this removes the project from your solution, but does not delete the corresponding files on disk.
3. Navigate to the IIS Express **ApplicationHost.config** file. By default, this file is located in:

   `%systemdrive%\Users\<YourWindowsUsername>\Documents\IISExpress\config`
4. Open the **ApplicationHost.config** file in a text editor. In the `<sites>` section, search for your site's name. In the `<bindings>` section of your site, you will see an element like this:

   `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56422:localhost" />`

   Change the port number (56422 in the above example) to anything you want. e.g.:

   `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />`

   and then map `mysite.dev` to `127.0.0.1` in your `hosts` file, and then open your website from "http://mysite.dev"; but that's outside the scope of this answer so I won't go into any more details)
5. In Solution Explorer, right-click the solution, select Add, and then select **Existing Web Site...**. In the Add Existing Web Site dialog box, make sure that the Local IIS tab is selected. Under IIS Express Sites, select the site for which you have changed the port number, then click OK.

Now you can access your website from your new hostname/port.

Credit of this option goes to [Saeb Amini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68080/saeb-amini) and the [original answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22206542/2592042)

---

Comment: sir, there is no web tab in the property window. Please check the screen shots. Is the way I have created Angular project is wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me the steps you did to start this new project?? right from opening the visual studio...

Comment: Open VS>>New Project>>Blank Solution>>Right click solution>>Add existing web site>>select Folder>>F5

Comment: Which version of Visual studio is it??

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0.21005.1 REL. Also your screen shots are not matching with my project. please check the screen shots in the question

Comment: in your steps `Add existing web site` you are choosing a existing project. And this existing project is not a web project. That is what I understand

Comment: Its an angular website. Previously build with the help of notepad++

Comment: @VikasBansal I have provided two options. Have a check. I did try it myself and got it working in the port 8080. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 6):

You can change the port in the Properties page of the project.

Right click the project and go to Properties or Alt + Enter.

Properties > Web.

Under Servers section, select "Specific Port" and provide one. :)

Comment: The property window does not have the `Web` option. Please check the screen shot in the question @sooraj

Comment: this works for me.. right click project, select properties and there's a web subcategory there, select that and then you will find Servers where you can set project URL.

Comment: It's important to right click the *project*, not the *solution*. There, you can change the URL. Often, the solution is at the top, the project(s) are below that level.