# How do I set the default port for a website in VS2015?

Tags: asp.net, port

I have downloaded the files for a Kentico project.
When I open the web site in VS2015 and right click the project to see the properties, there is a MISC section containing the Opened URL property.

This property is not enabled for editing.

How do I set it?

[image]

When I right click the Web Site name and select properties  I have

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set port by following these step.

1.In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the application and then select Properties. Click the Web tab.

2.In the Servers section, under Use Local IIS Web server, in the Project URL box change the port number.

3.To the right of the Project URL box, click Create Virtual Directory, and then click OK.

4.In the File menu, click Save Selected Items.

5.To verify the change, press CTRL+F5 to run the project. The new port number appears in the address bar of the browser.

But port number should not assigned already to other website..

Comment: I added an image of the solution above. Where do I right click the NAME of the application? is it the icon with the world ? that does not have a Properties menu option.

Comment: This is a web site, not an application...

Comment: Please check below answer

Answer (score 0):

Please check are these option available to you?

1.In Solution Explorer, click the name of the site.
2.In the Properties pane, click the down-arrow beside Use dynamic ports and select False from the drop-down list.
This will enable editing of the Port number property.
3.In the Properties pane, click the text box beside Port number and type in a port number.
4.Click outside of the Properties pane. This saves the property settings.

Comment: I think my question might be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013