# Can't change the port in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio

MSDN [says there should be an option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.ASPX) in the Properties pane to change the port.  There isn't.

[image]

How can you change the port of your local web server in Visual Studio 2015 community edition?

EDIT: I believe part of the problem may be that I'm doing a *web site projet*, not a *web application project* and those are different for how they allow you to access ports.

The bottom line is, I can't start up the server because something is using the same port.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36872160/369

Comment: Sorry @Blorgbeard but that didn't work...I can change all instances of the port in the .sln file, but when I open VS it just changes them all back :-(

Comment: Note for others with this problem: you may get the website you need by right-clicking IIS Express (in Windows, this is in the lower right hand side) and under View Sites selecting the site you're trying to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option doesn't exist in the enterprise edition either.  It seems to be stored in

[My Documents]\Visual Studio 2015\Projects[Your Web Site Name].vs\config\applicationhost.config

You should search for the current port number and replace it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but no dice.  If I change all instances of the port in the .sln file, then when VS opens the project, it just changes it all in that file.

Comment: The page you linked too above isn't for 2015, the highest version in the other versions list is 2010.  When I opened up a folder as a web site it also created a .webinfo file but I can't find any information on it's schema anywhere.

Comment: the page I linked to was the best documentation I could find; it doesn't list what version it is; let me know if you find something else that's supposed to be correct

Comment: No luck on better docs, I'm wondering if support for it was dropped at least in the ui.  Have a look at [My Documents]\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\[Your Web Site Name]\.vs\config\applicationhost.config and try searching for and editing the current port number.

Comment: That did it for me!  Thanks so much!  Feel free to post that as the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Somewhat misleading. I don't have my projects under [My Documents] and my server doesn't deliver a website. The path is just the project's path + .vs\config\applicationhost.config.

Answer (score 0):

Bases on @levininja's comment, I managed to solve the error by following the below instructions:

Open visual studio solution file **.sln* in your project folder and look for:

```
VWDPort = "54638"
```

*The default port number may be different than mine. In my case it is 54638.*

Change the port to the port number you want.

Comment: Seems to be ASP.NET exclusive.