# How can i change project start up URL in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Could I change project startup URL with custom port in visual studio 2015, my current project URL looks like **localhost:7620** now I just wanted to change **mydomain.com:8087**

Tried everything and even tried to search on google but didn't get any solution for VS2015.

Thank you.

Comment: For this you must 1) `Publish` your project and 2)Host it in `IIS` in a public IP server 3)Purchase a domain `mydomain.com` 4) Map this domain with your server IP.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy, I'd alreadyadded mydomain.com in my host config file, still i need to purchase domain ?

Comment: Yes.. you will have to purchase the domain from any hosting provider and then use their control panel to map your server IP to the domain name.

Comment: I've created simple web application which is running with local IIS, i don't want to purchase domain :(
hear is the similar steps i've followed http://www.locktar.nl/programming/custom-domain-url-in-iis-express-with-visual-studio-2013/

Comment: If you are looking to **host locally and not over the internet** here is a good blog.. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use IIS to set your own domain have you tried?

Comment: and also you can use Microsoft Azure

Comment: you can also refer to this question  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

What Mr. Rajshekar Reddy has mentioned is correct.

- Ignore next if you are trying to change to custome domain *

  if you are trying to change port number this would help.
   [Changing project port number in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-)    visual-studio-2013