# ASP MVC 4 + Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP MVC 4 project and the Web API.

[image: structure]

I wanna use Web API from the main application. i did this:

**WebAPI Project**

*WebApiConfig.cs*

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
                                           .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
}
```

*Global.asax*

```
protected void Application_Start() {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

*StatisticsController.cs*

```
public class StatisticsController : ApiController {
        TopUserFactory topUserFactory = new TopUserFactory();
        // GET api/statistics/topUsers
        [ActionName("topUsers")]
        public List<TopUser> Get() {
            return topUserFactory.Top10Users();
        }
}
```

But nothing happens when i go for `localhost:31003/api/statistics/{topUsers}`

How to use WebAPI project from other project?

Comment: When running locally the two sites will have different ports, make sure you're going to the correct one.

Comment: localhost:31003/api/statistics/topUsers try this

Comment: @ryan-searle how to define which port goes each site?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with multiple sites locally they will have different port numbers.

You can check the port numbers by clicking the IIS Express icon on your taskbar:

[image]

You can change the port number by adding a configuration:

[Changing project port number in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822209/changing-project-port-number-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

your code looks ok. it's very easy to get the routes wrong with WebAPI, ensure you're doing a parameter-less GET to http://localhost:31003/api/statistics/topUsers

failing that, use this tool:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/